# Format And join values of a table row cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to join table row cell values and then format the joined values to a format say

```
Lamivudine 98% (RSD = 1.3% ; n= 6)
```

and if the next checkbox in the next row is clicked then the new value should be

```
Lamivudine 98% (RSD = 1.3% ; n= 6) : Zidovudine 95% (RSD = 1.9% ; n= 9)
```

and so on and so forth....

here is the table rows

```
<tr class="assay_row">
    <td>Lamivudine</td>
    <td>98%</td>
    <td>1.3%</td>
    <td>6</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr class="assay_row">
    <td>Zidovudine</td>
    <td>95%</td>
    <td>1.9%</td>
    <td>6</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr class="assay_row">
    <td>Zidovudine</td>
    <td>1.5922307662924</td>
    <td>1.3636240087592</td>
    <td>9</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" /></td> 
</tr>
```

my js so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.case").click(myfunc);
});

function myfunc(ele) {

    var values = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
          function () {
               values.push($(this).text());
          });

    alert("val---" + values.join (", "));
 }
```

suggestions

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looping over all the `tr` elements, not the `td` elements. Within each row, you need to concatenate the `td` contents into the format you want.

```
function myfunc(ele) {

    var values = []
    $("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("tr").each(function () {
        var tds = $(this).children();
        values.push(tds.eq(0).text() + " " + tds.eq(1).text() + " (RSD = " + tds.eq(2).text() + " ; n = " + tds.eq(3).text() + ")");
    });

    alert("val---" + values.join (" : "));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oe8ev4c1/3/)